# Cannot create user page using gatein public api

Tags: gatein

When i create a user page using gatein public api i got an `org.gatein.api.EntityNotFoundException` exception. Here follows my code for creating user page

```
User user = PortalRequest.getInstance().getUser();

 Portal portal = PortalRequest.getInstance().getPortal();

f(portal.getPage(new PageId(user, pageName))==null){

Page newpage = portal.createPage(new PageId(user, pageName));// Here i got the exception

}
```

Here follows the stack trace of exception

```
 org.gatein.api.EntityNotFoundException: Site Site.Id[type=dashboard, name=supervisor] doesn't exist

    at org.gatein.api.PortalImpl.createPage(PortalImpl.java:271) [exo.portal.component.api-3.6.0.Final.jar:3.6.0.Final]

    at com.radiant.cisms.view.bean.DynamicDashBoardBean.createUserSpecificPage(DynamicDashBoardBean.java:146)

    at com.radiant.cisms.view.bean.DynamicDashBoardBean.saveNewPortlets(DynamicDashBoardBean.java:115)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]

    at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:132)

    ... 121 more
```

Also here i am attaching my portal-configuration.xml for reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.exoplaform.org/xml/ns/kernel_1_0.xsd http://www.exoplaform.org/xml/ns/kernel_1_0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://www.exoplaform.org/xml/ns/kernel_1_0.xsd">

    <external-component-plugins>
        <!-- The full qualified name of the UserPortalConfigService -->
        <target-component>org.exoplatform.portal.config.UserPortalConfigService
        </target-component>
        <component-plugin>
            <name>new.portal.config.user.listener</name>
            <set-method>initListener</set-method>
            <type>org.exoplatform.portal.config.NewPortalConfigListener</type>
            <description>this listener init the portal configuration
            </description>
            <init-params>
                <value-param>
                    <name>default.portal</name>
                    <description>The default portal for checking db is empty or not
                    </description>
                    <value>MPortal</value>
                </value-param>
                <value-param> <
                   <name>override</name>
                   <description>The flag parameter to decide if portal metadata is overriden on restarting server</description>
                   <value>true</value>
                </value-param>
                <object-param>
                    <name>portal.configuration</name>
                    <description>description</description>
                    <object type="org.exoplatform.portal.config.NewPortalConfig">
                        <field name="predefinedOwner">
                            <collection type="java.util.HashSet">
                                <value>
                                    <string>classic</string>
                                </value>
                                <value>
                                    <string>MPortal1</string>
                                </value>
                                <value>
                                    <string>MPortalForgotPassword</string>
                                </value>
                                <value>
                                    <string>MPortalWizard</string>
                                </value>
                               <value>
                                    <string>MPortalEndUser</string>
                                </value>
                            </collection>
                        </field>
                        <field name="ownerType">
                            <string>portal</string>
                        </field>
                        <field name="templateLocation">
                            <string>war:/conf/gtec/</string>
                        </field>
                        <field name="importMode"> 
                             <string>overwrite</string>
                        </field>
                    </object>
                </object-param>
            </init-params>
        </component-plugin>
    </external-component-plugins>

</configuration>
```

Can you help me to give a reason about this issue?

Comment: I guess you use GateIn 3.6 ? I tested your snippet of code in a basic portlet, and my page has been successfully created. Can you try with a fresh GateIn ? Did you add some custom configuration that could impact users' pages ?

Comment: @Thomas I am using fresh GateIn. But i do it in my own portal applcation. But i can create page when `SiteKey` instead of `user` like follows `portal.createPage(new PageId("newPortal", "myPage"));`

Comment: The exception says that the dashboard of your user has not been created. The dashboard is created when the user is created, by the listener org.exoplatform.portal.config.UserPortalConfigListener declared in the  file portal.war/WEB-INF/conf/portal/portal-configuration.xml. Did you remove/overwrite this configuration ?

Comment: Ya i edited it  you can find out my portal-configuration.xml from above. Is there is any issue on my portal-configuration.xml?

Comment: @Thomas I resolved the issue in one level. I can create user page for users who are under `predefinedOwner` tag in portal-configuration.xml. But i cant create user portal for users which i created programatically (I think because they are not in `predefindOwner` category). How can i add users to `predefindOwner` category programatically?

Comment: How do you create your users programmatically ? Do you enable the broadcast (which calls the listener I mentionned above) ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41926/discussion-between-anish-antony-and-thomas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error says that the dashboard of your user does not exist. The dashboard is created automatically when the user is created, thanks to the listener org.exoplatform.portal.config.UserPortalConfigListener declared in the file portal.war/WEB-INF/conf/portal/portal-configuration.xml.
So I guess in your case, the listener has not been triggred when the user has been created.

If you create your users programmatically, you have to be sure that the broadcast option is enabled (which will triggered the listeners), by setting the second argument of the createUser method to true : orgService.getUserHandler().createUser(user, true);